# Extract all substrings from a string that are between a word and a delimiter using regex c++

Tags: c++, regex

I have the following query:

```
std::string query =
"ODR+1"
"DPT+::SFO"
"ARR+::MKE"
"ODR+2"
"DPT+::MKE"
"ARR+::SFO";
```

I am trying to extract from all the segments starting with `ARR` or `DPT` the values after `::`.  I wrote the following regular expression `[DPT|ARR]\+\:\:(.*)`. It worked when I tested it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

When I wrote the following C++ code. I got the following output:

```
DPT+::SFO'ARR+::MKE'ODR+2'DPT+::MKE'ARR+::SFO'
```

The output is wrong I really just want to extract SFO and MKO. How can I modify the regex query to just extract these patterns

---

```
   #include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string query =
    "ODR+1'"
    "DPT+::SFO'"
    "ARR+::MKE'"
    "ODR+2'"
    "DPT+::MKE'"
    "ARR+::SFO'";
    
    std::regex regulaExpression("(DPT|ARR).*::(.*)\\'");

    std::sregex_iterator iter(query.begin(), query.end(), regulaExpression);
    std::sregex_iterator end;

    while(iter != end)
    {
        std::cout << iter->str() << std::endl;
        ++iter;
    }
}
```

---

## UPDATE

I updated the code:

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{  
    const char *target  =
            "ODR+1'"
            "DPT+::SFO'"
            "ARR+::MKE'"
            "ODR+2'"
            "DPT+::MKE'"
            "ARR+::SFO'";

    std::regex rgx("(DPT|ARR).*?::(.*?)'");
    for(auto it = std::cregex_iterator(target, target + std::strlen(target), rgx);
             it != std::cregex_iterator();
           ++it)
    {
        std::cmatch match = *it;
        std::cout << match[2].str() << '\n';
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Now it is allowing me to retrieve the following. Which is exactly what I want. But I dont know why it work.

```
SFo                                                                                                                                                                                     
MKE                                                                                                                                                                                     
MKE                                                                                                                                                                                     
SFO
```

It worked by why did I have to use `std::cout << match[2].str() << '\n';`

Comment: `[DPT|ARR]` no, not really. You probably want `DPT|ARR`.

Comment: More importantly, `.*` matches everything to the end and you don't have any newlines in the query to stop it.

Comment: yes but in the regular expression Isay that I want the word that I am looking for to be between DPT and '

Comment: Greedy regex matching, google it

Comment: What about something like: `(?:DPT|ARR)(?:[^':]*:)+:([^']*)`

Comment: @AdrianMaire I have a question. your regrex worked. "std::cout << match[1].str() << '\n';"

Can you explain it. Mine worked too but with "std::cout << match[2].str() << '\n';"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your regular expression:

```
(DPT|ARR).*?::(.*?)'
```

First part `(DPT|ARR)` will get strings starting by `DPT` or `ARR` but will also save it, so the first element of your result `match[1]` has this value. To avoid this, use the non-capturing group: `(?:    )`

Second part `.*?` is the issue: it capture all, including `::`, so your regex does never find the separator. You want to search for everything except `:`, and possibly also without `'` (to avoid a wrong section to propagate to others): `(?:[^':]*:)+:`
The first part search for something up to the first `:`, and then check there is another `:` just after. If you are sure this part has no single `:`, you may simplify it.

Finally, you get the required string: `([^']*)` up to the first `'`. The parenthesis are there only to capture the content, so you may retrieve it with `match[1]`

```
(?:DPT|ARR)(?:[^':]*:)+:([^']*)
```